# changing timout in efibootmgr

Tags: timeout, efibootmgr

On command-line I issued the command:
sudo efibootmgr --timeout 30

This did not work, and the reported error is:
"Could not set Timeout: Invalid argument"

I also issued the same command with -t instead of --timeout, but the end result was the same.  If you know what I am doing wrong, please help.

Just in case it may be relevant to the question, I am running Ubuntu Mate 20.04 LTS on a brand new desktop from CyberPowerPC.

Comment: Just in case this might be relevant to the question, I would like add that I am running Ubuntu-Mate 20.04 LTS.

Comment: Do not post added info in comments, but add to your original question. What brand/model system. Some like HP do not support some changes by efibootmgr.

Comment: Is the system installed in UEFI mode?